# vb2010 pass data from one form to another

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to pass a value of a textbox on frmMain to a textbox on frmDepartment. I have tried the following code which I thought would work but it dosen't. I ma a new user to VB and come from a php background where it would have been a simple task of setting a seesion. Can anyone help with this? If you need to see more code, please ask. many thanks

```
txtDeptCustomer.Text = frmMain.txtCustomerActive.Text
```

In frmMain, I am getting value like this:

```
Dim value As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
txtCustomerActive.Text = CType(value, String)

Private Sub btnDepts_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDepts.Click
        frmDepartment.Show()
End Sub
```

Which is showing in frmMain ok.

In frmDepartment I have this code

```
Private Sub txtDeptCustomer_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDeptCustomer.TextChanged
    'Dim customer As String

    txtDeptCustomer.Text = frmMain.txtCustomerActive.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: We need some more code.

Comment: And what you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: Are both forms running at the same time?

Comment: @campagnolo frmMain is running and I am trying to get the value on a button click

Comment: create a variable in your form to hold the string result along with an accessor method.  when the user clicks ok, close what ever you have, put the value of the textbox in the variable and access it using the accessor method.  it may be an issue that your textbox has already been disposed...but dont know for sure as there is not enough code to go off of.

Comment: @Sorceri I have included more code above but do not understand your answer. I am new to vb. Thanks

Comment: @Craig when I say it doesn't work, it is not putting the value into the textbox in frmDepartment

Comment: Use the debugger to see whether the problem is in reading or writing and figure out what's happening from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of putting the code within the txtDeptCustomer.TextChanged sub, try putting it within the frmDepartment_load:

```
Private Sub frmDepartment_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load            
    txtDeptCustomer.Text = frmMain.txtCustomerActive.Text
End Sub
```

or you could set the frmDepartment text box text on the frmMain button click:

```
Private Sub btnDepts_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDepts.Click
        frmDepartment.txtDeptCustomer.Text = txtCustomerActive.Text
        frmDepartment.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much rsmith. You have made a newbie very happy :-)

Comment: no problem. i'd probably go with setting it on the button click